# Jquery multiple person search on one page why won't results populate?

Tags: jquery

I have this page which has three peson searchs on them. Basically it's a textbox and button. When you click the button it takes the text in the associated textbox and should populate the associated results with list data.

```
    <div class="personcontainer">
        <div class="peoplesearchdiv" >

        <input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
        <input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn" />
        <div class="peopleresultsdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="personguid" />

<div class="personcontainer">
        <div class="peoplesearchdiv" >

        <input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
        <input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn" />
        <div class="peopleresultsdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="personguid" />

<div class="personcontainer">
        <div class="peoplesearchdiv" >

        <input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
        <input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn" />
        <div class="peopleresultsdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="personguid" />
```

Ok, so the jquery to try to get this working is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {

    var query = $(this).closest('.personcontainer').find('.searchpersontxtbox').val();

    $.get('/People/GetPeople/', { 'query': query }, function (data) {         

        $(this).closest('.peoplesearchdiv').find('.peopleresultsdiv').html(data);

    });

});
```

Returned from GetPeople is basic list data eg.

```
<ul>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
</ul>
```

So what I was wanting to happen was the list data to populate the html to the peopleresultsdiv within the same personscontainer.

Doesn't work though.

To eliminate it being the GetPeople method I changed the jquery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {

        var query = $(this).closest('.personcontainer').find('.searchpersontxtbox').val();

        $.get('/People/GetPeople/', { 'query': query }, function (data) {         

            $(this).closest('.peoplesearchdiv').find('.peopleresultsdiv').html("<ul><li>Cat</li><li>Dog</li></ul>");

        });

    });
```

Still doesn't work.

So I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {

        var query = $(this).closest('.personcontainer').find('.searchpersontxtbox').val();

        $(this).closest('.peoplesearchdiv').find('.peopleresultsdiv').html("<ul><li>Cat</li><li>Dog</li></ul>");

        $.get('/People/GetPeople/', { 'query': query }, function (data) {


        });

    });
```

Hmmmmmm. Now the list is appearing. Obviously not what I want though because I'm not getting to populate from the method.

So it appears the closest find won't work inside the get?

Anyone know why how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside $.get having $(this) doesn't return peopleresultsdiv.

So, you can get the required div outside $.get and have it in a variable, and use that inside $.get